# How to setup an HTTP listener on localhost in a OSX App

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, oauth, macos-catalina

I am trying to build an OSX application using swift and storyboard. I am implementing Google OAuth for the app. Following the google guide https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#sample-authorization-urls, I am opening a browser with the a loopback authorisation url (i.e. after signing in, it loopbacks to localhost where the url contains authorisation code and other meta data.

To give a better overview of how the authentication workflow works:

1. User selects authorise button in app
2. Browser opens up with an url like:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
 scope=email%20profile&
 response_type=code&
 state=security_token%3D138r5719ru3e1%26url%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Foauth2.example.com%2Ftoken&
 redirect_uri=http%3A//127.0.0.1%3A9004&
 client_id=client_id
```

3. The google account chooser and permissions consent screen renders and prompts user to give permission..
4. Once user gives permission, the page redirects to localhost with the authorisation code or the error (when not permitted). The redirect url looks like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9004/?code=auth_code&
scope=email%20profile%20openid%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&
authuser=0&
prompt=consent
```

So now I want the parameter `code` in my app. Google document says I have to create an HTTP listener in order to get the parameters. So I want to setup an HTTP listener at that port (9004) and get the params. What HTTP library can I use to solve this problem?

I haven't tried to involve myself with any oauth library for osx and I want to implement myself but if there is a library which solves this problem with limited boilerplate suggest them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [AppAuth](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS) framework for macOS and iOS. It takes care of all of this for you, and includes an option to set up an HTTP server on the loopback interface.

Comment: The problem of course is that Chrome has started to block all `http` connections and AppAuth seems to be hardcoded to use `http`.